# Setup.exe crashes when trying to install application

Tags: c#, installation

VS 2005 SP3

I have developed application and used the setup project to create the msi.

When I go to install on the users computer it crashes when I double click the setup.exe. It displays a message box saying to you want to send this error message to microsoft.

This happens on only 2 machines out of 6.

The 2 machines that are having this problem are running windows XP Pro SP2, and the other one SP3.

I am thinking does it have anything to do with anti-virus or anti-spyware software running on the users computers?

The information I get from the crash is below for both machines.

Many thanks for any advice,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DATABASE>
<EXE NAME="CATSoftphone.exe" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="CATSoftphone.msi" SIZE="1458688" CHECKSUM="0xA819F3CD" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="CATSoftphone.exe" SIZE="329312" CHECKSUM="0xDB3CECF0" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x80164D54" LINKER_VERSION="0x80000" LINK_DATE="09/23/2005 10:45:29" UPTO_LINK_DATE="09/23/2005 10:45:29" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="kernel32.dll" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="989696" CHECKSUM="0x2D998938" BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Windows NT BASE API Client DLL" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781 (xpsp_sp3_gdr.090321-1317)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xFE572" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" LINK_DATE="03/21/2009 14:06:58" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/21/2009 14:06:58" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
</EXE>
</DATABASE>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DATABASE>
<EXE NAME="CATSoftphone.exe" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="CATSoftphone.msi" SIZE="1458688" CHECKSUM="0xA819F3CD" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="CATSoftphone.exe" SIZE="329312" CHECKSUM="0xDB3CECF0" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x80164D54" LINKER_VERSION="0x80000" LINK_DATE="09/23/2005 10:45:29" UPTO_LINK_DATE="09/23/2005 10:45:29" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="kernel32.dll" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="986112" CHECKSUM="0xEBE25B3D" BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.3119" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.3119" PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.3119" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Windows NT BASE API Client DLL" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.3119 (xpsp_sp2_qfe.070416-1259)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xF995F" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.3119" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.3119" LINK_DATE="04/16/2007 16:07:27" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/16/2007 16:07:27" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
</EXE>
</DATABASE>
```

Comment: Have you considered running the setup exe in a debugger?

Comment: Hello, I am not sure what you mean by running the setup.exe in the debugger. I have created the setup.exe and the setup.msi files. I place both of them on the user computer and double click the setup.exe file. A crash happens immediately. However, if I double click the setup.msi, then the application installs as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this had something to do with the software that was running on the computer. After a complete re-install the problem on longer exits.